# Simplify the JS that forces IE11 to open a link in google chrome

Tags: javascript, html, url

I did have a short cut to a post here that explained how to combine the code below to make it easier for me to use it on muliple links.

Our company (for the time being is forcing us to use IE11) and I need to be able to add a link to a webpage that opens it in google chrome. The code I have is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openURL1()
        {
        var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        shell.run("Chrome https://hotmail.com/");
        }
        function openURL2()
        {
        var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        shell.run("Chrome https://google.com/");
        }
</script>

<TD COLSPAN="2" STYLE= WIDTH="100"> <input type="button" style ="background-color:grey" onclick="openURL1()" value="Support Net"></TD>
<TD COLSPAN="2" STYLE= WIDTH="100"> <input type="button" style ="background-color:grey" onclick="openURL2()" value="Communities"></TD>
```

Just want to display link to click on thats all. 1 I don't need to do anything but i have several links that I need to add. HTML code I can work my way round but I am still a newbie when it comes to JS and struggle still. cheers

Comment: so pass in the link to a function? basic string concatenation

Comment: @epascarello could you show me how i do that ? and can i do it without the button ?

Comment: function openUrl(url) { shell.run("Chrome " + url); }

Answer (score 1):

If i read your request correct, you're looking for something like:

```
function openURL(url) {
  let shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
  shell.run("Chrome " + url);
}
```

a single function with the url as a parameter, so you can reuse it?

Html body portion following your current example:

```
<TD COLSPAN="2" STYLE="WIDTH: 100;"> <input type="button" style ="background-color:grey;" onclick="openURL('https://hotmail.com/')" value="Support Net"></TD>
<TD COLSPAN="2" STYLE="WIDTH: 100;"> <input type="button" style ="background-color:grey;" onclick="openURL('https://google.com/')" value="Communities"></TD>
<TD COLSPAN="2" STYLE="WIDTH: 100;"> <input type="button" style ="background-color:grey;" onclick="openURL('https://stackoverflow.com/')" value="Helpful People"></TD>
```

Comment: cheers @partylich yes that looks very familiar. Now how do i use that for the link in the html body ?

Comment: is there a way to not use a button ? use a link instead ? <a

Comment: The `onclick` property should be available for any html element. So there isn't much technical limit in what type of element you choose, button, link, or otherwise.